# BluebirdJS complained promise was created but in a handler none were returned

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, bluebird

I saw the other post which suggest enabling an env variable to silence it. I don't want to silence the warning. I want to fix the warning. That means, I don't want to implement BLUEBIRD_W_FORGOTTEN_RETURN=0

This is the code where I'm getting the message "Warning: a promise was created in a  handler but was not returned from it"

```
metaData = new PatientMetaData();
this.promises.metaData = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  metaData.fetch({
    success: function(){
      resolve(metaData);
    },
    error: function(err){
      reject(err);
    }
  });
});
```

I added "return" before this.promises.metaData, warning still appears.
I added it before resolve and reject, warning still appears.
I added it before metaData.fetch, warning still appears.
I added it before new, I got an error "Unexpected Token"

Answer (score 2):

Adding `return null;` will tell bluebird that this is intentional.

Source: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html

Comment: I added return null; but it didn't fix it. LOL